# ¿Cómo recorrer todos los datos de json y mostrarlos en HTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5, json

Tengo un json simple

`[{"id": 4,"nombres": "Juan"}, {"id": 5,"nombres": "Carlos"}, {"id": 7,"nombres": "Maria"}]`

Lo llamo usando ajax

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: base_url + "nombres.php",
    data: {
      rol: usuarios,
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
      //console.log(result);
      const resp = JSON.parse(result);
      $(".cards-accounts").empty();
      var show;
      for (let x of resp) {
        const names = x.names; 
        console.log(names);
        show += `
        <div class="card-container">
        <span class="pro">${names}</span>
                           
        </div>
        `;
      }
      $(".cards-accounts").empty().append(show);
    },
  });
```

Con esto logro mostrar los resultados en un div, pero siempre me muestra un `undefined` al principio. Debería tener tres divs con los nombres del json, pero me muestra 4 siendo siempre el primero un 'undefined'. En consola no me muestra ningun error. Realmente no entiendo cuál podría ser el problema, o cómo quitar ese `undefined` que se muestra al mostrar los datos en HTML.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia esto, te fallaba nombres en vez de names e inicializar show:

```
const resp = JSON.parse(result);
      $(".cards-accounts").empty();
      var show = '';
      for (let x of resp) {
        const names = x.nombres; 
        console.log(names);
        show += `
        <div class="card-container">
        <span class="pro">${names}</span>
                           
        </div>
        `;
      }
      $(".cards-accounts").empty().append(show);
```

Comment: gracias no me a había fijado, pero no ese no es el problema

Comment: muchas gracias vi el error.